# React event target value in onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

What is the difference between

```
onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setInsertedTitle(value)}
```

and

```
onChange={setInsertedTitle}
```

When should one or another be used?

Comment: The second one will pass the entire synthetic react event to `setInsertedTitle`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setInsertedTitle(value)}` you are passing the current target value as a parameter.

It is because onChange generates an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), and you access the value by event.target.value ...

```
event: {
  target: {
    value: "string"
  }
}
```

On the other hand, when you use the function like in onChange={setInsertedTitle}, it receives the event.

You can see it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-fast-krrib?file=/src/App.js

Comment: this one is the simpler answer, straightforward

Answer (score 4):

Look at what each does and spot the differences:

```js
onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setInsertedTitle(value)}
```

- Creates an arrow function (let's call it `func`)
- Whenever `onChange`/`func` gets called, e.g. `func(event)`:

  - It uses [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to set `value` to the value of `event.target.value`
  - It calls `setInsertedTitle` with `value` (therefore `event.target.value`)

In the other case:

```js
onChange={setInsertedTitle}
```

When `onChange` gets called with `event`, we directly call `setInsertedTitle` with `event`.

Therefore the main difference is whether it passes `event.target.value` or just `event`.

Comment: That's a very detailed explanation, thanks man, it was useful!

Answer (score 2):

The first one passes a function to `onChange` that, when called, will get the `value` of the `target` element of the event (this is probably an `input` element, so `target` will be that `input` element) and pass that value to `setInsertedTitle`. So when the event occurs, `setInsertedTitle` gets called with a string (the value of the input).

The second one will directly pass `setInsertedTitle` to `onChange`. When the event occurs, `setInsertedTitle` will get called with an **event object** rather than the value of the input.

For the avoidance of doubt: The first one is correct, the second one is incorrect. (Even if you wanted to have an event object in your state data — which you almost certainly don't — you can't just keep the one you're passed; you're not allowed to keep them as they get reused [I think that's going to change at some point].)